# Replace host name in a URL string

Tags: ruby, regex

**Original question**

I have a string URL, and I need to extract the subdomains of the url.
My URL would look like:

```
user[:href] = "https://www.example.com/user-detail/1231-N-F-Albert"
```

I need to extract:

```
"https://www.example.com/"
```

and return:

```
"/user-detail/1231-N-F-Albert"
```

Is there any method that removes the host name and returns just the subdomain? I tried with:

```
URI.parse(user[:href]).host.replace("")
```

but it returned empty. Any other way to achieve it?

---

**New question**

I have changed the question. I need to extract:

```
"https://www.example.com/user-detail"
```

and return:

```
"1231-N-F-Albert"
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I tried with regular expression, but it didn't work.

Comment: @rubyist : check my answer for your updated question

Answer (score 2):

Use a URI parser and just return the path:

```
URI.parse("https://www.example.com/user-detail/1231-N-F-Albert").path
#=> "/user-detail/1231-N-F-Albert"
```

Comment: Or use `Addressable::URI` if you need better UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Hope it is clean and easy to understand.

```
require 'uri'
URI("http://www.mydomain.qwe/directory").path
# => "/directory"
```

Answer (score -1):

use **[Ruby#URI](https://apidock.com/ruby/URI)**

```
> require 'uri'
# To get path from URL
> URI.parse("https://www.example.com/user-detail/1231-N-F-Albert").path
#=> "/user-detail/1231-N-F-Albert"
```

---

```
# To get last segment of url
> URI.parse("https://www.example.com/user-detail/1231-N-F-Albert").path.split('/').last
#=> "1231-N-F-Albert"
```